# Request merge azure-web-app-service with azure-web-sites

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I see that, there are already synonyms to azure-web-sites

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/azure-web-sites/synonyms

- azure-web-apps
- azure-app-service

but, somehow,

- azure-web-app-service

missed getting linked to that. could someone with enough points/privilege suggest and take care of this.

Comment: According to the excerpt, `Azure App Service Web Apps (formerly known as Azure Web Sites) ` which seems to me that this suggestion is backwards. Shouldn't [azure-web-app-service] be the main tag? Searching "azure web services] returns [this web app service page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/) as the first result

Comment: I am not too worried about the main tag. Just want them linked because I work on azure web apps a lot the tag above is confusing me. and, yes, I agree, azure-web-app-service should be the main tag, but microsoft changes these names so often, as long as they are linked, it should be fine.

Comment: I went ahead and swapped them and approved the synonym. Will wait a while to do the merge in case anyone objects

Comment: awesome and super cool :)